# Search based on Text Attributes

Tags: full-text-search

Is there any way to search text based on its colour and other attributes such as font size, style, etc in MS Word, other readers and editors.

[image: Text Search based on its attributes]

Also the text can vary in its size, style, etc. Those are not included in the sample image. Plz help out solve this problem in Word atleast.

Comment: Convert to html, then use an html parser, then find the attributes that you want.

Comment: Any in built provisions provided by MS Word instead porting to HTML ??